# Changing dataframe value dtype with mixed types efficiently

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dtype

I'm working with a scientific data set where measurable values are represented numerically and non-measurable values are represented by a default string "Present < RDL".  The first roadblock met while working with this data is the difficulty that comes from having two different data types, string and float, in a column.  `pd.read_csv` appears to cast all values as strings in certain columns (not sure why as of now).  So I would like to have all numerical values as an appropriate type, like float, and all "Present < RDL" to remain as strings.

I have figured out a way around the mixed dtypes, and I can apply the logic to individual columns, but for some reason when I apply the same logic in a loop, it doesn't work:

```
# Dummy data:
lst = ['1.01', '2.05', 'Present < RDL', '3.50', '1.23', 'Present < RDL', '1.72']
lst2 = ['1.2', 'Present < RDL', '0.75', '1.53', '2.34', 'Present < RDL', '0.96']
data = {'test1': lst, 'test2': lst2}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Works to convert numeric values in series from string to float.
lst = []
for i in data.test1:
    try:
        lst.append(float(i))
    except:
        lst.append(i)
test = pd.Series(lst)

# Verify that numbers have been converted to numeric type.
map(type, test)

# Now, the same logic looping through the dataframe columns:
for col in data.columns:
    lst = []
    for i in col:
        try:
            lst.append(float(i))
        except:
            lst.append(i)
    col = pd.DataFrame(lst)

# Shows no change in dtypes.
map(type, data.test1)
```

I've observed a similar trend with pandas functions, in addition to having more trouble to get them to work consistently.

```
data.test1 = pd.to_numeric(data.test1, errors='ignore')
```

I realize my first solution is probably not going to be as elegant as the pandas functions, so I'm open to any and all suggestions for how to achieve the goal.  Thanks for reading.

---

Update:

After integrating the answer below, I was able to fix the looping issue:

```
for col in data.columns:
    data[col] = pd.to_numeric(data[col], errors='coerce').fillna(data[col])
```

Comment: You can't, pandas enforces common types inside a column so everything will be of type "object". You should probably use a sentinel value or create a new column with boolean indicators to locate the problematic values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.to_numeric` with argument `errors='coerce'` to convert the strings to `Nan` then finally `fillna` these with the strings in your original column:

```
data['test1'] = pd.to_numeric(data['test1'], errors='coerce').fillna(data['test1'])
```

If we then check the types of each row:

```
print(data['test1'].apply(type))

0    <class 'float'>
1    <class 'float'>
2      <class 'str'>
3    <class 'float'>
4    <class 'float'>
5      <class 'str'>
6    <class 'float'>
Name: test1, dtype: object
```

We see the mixed type column as you want.

---

Now we can actually do calculations on our column, obviously for strings it will give weird results, but that's the downside of mixed type columns:

```
data['test1'] * 2

0                          2.02
1                           4.1
2    Present < RDLPresent < RDL
3                             7
4                          2.46
5    Present < RDLPresent < RDL
6                          3.44
Name: test1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Ok, it would appear that the root of my problem was with the `errors='ignore'` argument.  I was under the impression it would simply leave the value untouched if an error occurred, but it is apparently more nuanced than that.  Thanks.

Comment: How would you loop it across columns?  I'm having problems using for "col in data.columns:"